# I can't Install EasyTether

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, easytether

I'm trying to install EasyTether via the deb package provided on their drivers page.

I ran the command `sudo dpkg -i easytether`
and I got this:

```
[sudo] password for icedborn: 
(Reading database ... 232605 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack easytether_0.8.7-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking easytether (0.8.7-1) over (0.8.7-1) ...
Setting up easytether (0.8.7-1) ...
```

Then I ran the command easytether connect
and I got this message:

```
easytether: command not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See http://www.mobile-stream.com/easytether/android_faq.html#linuxsetup. It should be `easytether-usb` or `easytether-bluetooth`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure the package has been installed correctly:

```
dpkg -l easytether | grep "^ii"
```

if you get nothing, it means package is not correctly installed.

After that find about package binaries:

```
dpkg -L easytether | grep '/bin/
```

it gives you a list of binaries which you can run. Use them to run the program.